# Memory footprint constantly increasing in WPF/Winform application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, winforms-interop

This issue seems to be isolated to the part of my program where I have a Winform control hosted inside a WPF window.

The user is presented with X number of rows, and may click Edit on any row to bring up another window (<< this is the window with the Winform control in it).

Every time a new selection is made, and a new Edit window is loaded, the memory usage goes up between 1 and 4 megs. I have tried nulling/disposing all the objects I can when that window is closed, but it hasn't made a difference.

It is ONLY this window that causes the memory to go up consistently and it never goes back down. Even if I close all but the Main window, the memory footprint stays where it is.

Comment: This could happen for a number of reasons. Are you detaching event handlers as needed? Are you disposing disposable instances?

Comment: I'm disposing of things that have Dispose() available. Using ' = null' for a few other things. What is the best way to ensure event handlers are detached?

Comment: Worth nothing that the garbage collector won't necessarily run after the Winform window is closed. It'll only run when it feels the need to. Have you forced a gc (e.g. using PerfView) to see if the memory comes down?

Comment: Tried forcing GC, Windows doesn't seem to care.

Answer (score 2):

Simpliest solution is to make memory snapshot of your memory before opening window and after and see what new object were allocated. You can do it with memory profiler [dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) for example.

Also in dotMemory you can automatically see what event handlers are leaked.

Answer (score 0):

Alexey has said how I would approach this problem as well. Profiling the memory can show a lot of issues with a program.

Microsoft provides two tools that you can use for this. One is the [CLR Profiler](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273) and the other is the [Performance Analysis Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) which also includes CLR memory information. I would go with the former of these two.